# FullCalendar custom icon / element at toolbar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

We can create custom buttons in FullCalendar with 1 icon (and only specific icons).

I have a custom component

```html
<icons code="menu" from="material-symbols-outlined"></icons>
```

Which outputs

```html
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
```

Can I inject custom components (icons) into Fullcalendar custom buttons?

I prefer to put 2 icons in 1 button, for example, search and right icons (if the button is clicked, it will go to the latest event week).

Comment: The available icons you can use on your buttons depends on your theme - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/buttonIcons

Comment: @ADyson Yeah I could use those icons, but I would like it better if I could inject my component into that button (<icons>), because then I could for example display a tooltip when hovering that button etc.

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing in the fullCalendar API which supports that currently. You can consider making a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) to the maintainers of the library. In the meantime you might just have to use JS to replace the contents of the buttons in the DOM after they've been rendered, I guess. You should be able to identify the button by its class - e.g. if you defined the button as `myCustomButton` in the fullCalendar options then it'll have the class `fc-myCustomButton-button` in the rendered HTML (as of fullCalendar 6, anyway)